# Where do Vaishnava Scriptures declare Shiva as supreme god?

Tags: vishnu, shiva, puranas

Some Shavaite scriptures declare Vishnu as supreme in some cases. Is there any mention of Shiva as supreme deity in Vaishnava scriptures?

Comment: Also the Narada purana mentions Vishnu and Shiva "are one and the same." (http://www.astrojyoti.com/naradapurana-5.htm)

Comment: When any scripture declares Shiva as supreme it means that scripture is praising his antaryami Shriman Narayana, same is true for Shaiva,  Vaishnava, or Shakta Purana.

Comment: @Parikshitha I also studied it somewhere but unable to recall, can you please be kind enough and tell which Shavaite scriptures declare Vishnu as supreme in some cases?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bhagvata puran;

SB 8.7.21

> The prajāpatis said: O greatest of all demigods, Mahādeva, Supersoul
>   of all living entities and cause of their happiness and prosperity, we
>   have come to the shelter of your lotus feet. Now please save us from
>   this fiery poison, which is spreading all over the three worlds.

SB 8.7.22

> O lord, you are the cause of bondage and liberation of the entire
>   universe because you are its ruler. Those who are advanced in
>   spiritual consciousness surrender unto you, and therefore you are the
>   cause of mitigating their distresses, and you are also the cause of
>   their liberation. We therefore worship Your Lordship.

SB 8.7.23

> O lord, you are self-effulgent and supreme. You create this material
>   world by your personal energy, and you assume the names Brahmā, Viṣṇu
>   and Maheśvara when you act in creation, maintenance and annihilation.

SB 8.7.24

> You are the cause of all causes, the self-effulgent, inconceivable,
>   impersonal Brahman, which is originally Parabrahman. You manifest
>   various potencies in this cosmic manifestation.

SB 8.7.25

> O lord, you are the original source of Vedic literature. You are the
>   original cause of material creation, the life force, the senses, the
>   five elements, the three modes and the mahat-tattva. You are eternal
>   time, determination and the two religious systems called truth [satya]
>   and truthfulness [ṛta]. You are the shelter of the syllable om, which
>   consists of three letters a-u-m.

Source; https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/8/7

Comment: Describe the answer in your own words rather than just copy pasting. See [The copy-paste issue, Hinduism version](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48/the-copy-paste-issue-hinduism-version). For the verses, you can quote them. But there should be something in your own words also.

Comment: "greatest of all demigods"..LOL actually he is the ONLY Bhagavana as per the Vedas, which these people will translate as " Supreme Personality of Godhead" or something like that :D

Comment: How beautiful. It shows how stupid all are to fight over Vishnu and Shiva. They both indeed are one.

Comment: @Rickross, according to your understanding of Vedas, maybe. You do realize there are different interpretations right ?

Comment: What i meant is as far as the usage of the term Bhagavan is concerned then in Vedas its only used for Rudra Bhagavan in the entire Vedas. Its not used for any other Deities in the whole of Vedas. Its actually not at all a question of going deep into it or understanding (in ur words).@ram